# HTML5 Audio Safari Woes

Tags: jquery, safari, html5-audio

Just a quick edit based on feedback: a major part of this problem is my inexperience. If you can give me some tips on how to investigate/debug I'd really appreciate it. Thanks again. Niall

I have this function/plugin for playing sounds when an element is clicked:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.attachSound = function (soundSrc)
    {
    return this.each(function(index){
        var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
        if (audioElement.canPlayType('audio/mpeg') == '')
        {
        soundSrc = soundSrc.replace('.mp3','.ogg');
        }
        audioElement.setAttribute('src', soundSrc);
        $(this).click(function() {
        audioElement.play();
        });
    })
    }
})( jQuery );
```

And here's an example of how I call it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#laughter-button').attachSound('sounds/laughter-elf.mp3');
    $('#laughter-button2').attachSound('sounds/laughter-santa.mp3');
})
```

So far it's working in Chrome, FF, Opera, and Safari (all current versions, I didn't get to testing on IE yet). The problem I'm having is in Safari, it works for the first user click only. One of the ways I wanted to use this function was as part of a sound-based memory game so as it is it won't do. Any ideas?

I'm quite inexperienced at programming and I've never tried flash fallback techniques but I'm willing to look into how that works. Perhaps, though, there's a better way or you can point me in the right direction?

Thank you,
Niall

Comment: Sorry to say, but,  in my opinion, the new "Great HTML5 Audio/Video API" is not so great. If you want good cross browser compat, you're best off relying on a plugin that's been around a few years. I've personally tested every feature of this new api, and if I took the time I could probably find your problem, but fact is, it's just crappy and not worth the waste of time or headache. Maybe they'll fix it with HTML6. lol

Comment: @SpYk3HH Thank you! I'll keep my eye out for HTML6!

Comment: yea, sorry i can't be more helpful right now. maybe this weekend. right now i have a headache, and just thinking about HTML5 audio api is making it worse, lol

Answer (score 0):

Check if Safari supports mp3 audio / Html5 on http://html5test.com/

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a compromise solution. This solution creates a new audio on each click instead of just on document.ready. The drawback is it's less efficient but at least it's working in Safari. And there are ways I can improve it. Right now, though I'm happy enough with this solution simply because it works. Having said that, though, I'm certainly open to better solutions if you can think of one. I'll probably end up trying to combine this code with browser sniffing or something. Thanks to everyone who got me thinking in different ways about the problem.
Niall

```
(function($){
    $.fn.attachSound = function (soundSrc)
    {
    return this.each(function(index){
        $(this).click(function() {
        var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
            if (audioElement.canPlayType('audio/mpeg') == '')
            {
            soundSrc = soundSrc.replace('.mp3','.ogg');
            }
        audioElement.setAttribute('src', soundSrc);
        audioElement.play();
        });
    })
    }
})( jQuery );
```